# i installed opencv-python getting import error

Tags: opencv, jupyter-notebook, importerror

`import cv2`

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 import cv2
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cv2__init__.py in 
>         3 import sys
>         4 
>   ----> 5 from .cv2 import *
>         6 from .data import *
>         7
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Comment: Can you mention on which system you installed it and what was the command you used ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using Anaconda. If so don't use pip as it can break your environment, use conda.

You can try by
first going to "anaconda-prompt" using windows search and then run the command as below:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

or any other from https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can uninstall and install opencv. This usually happens when you download package at a different file location or the package itself is not installed properly. 
I suggest using this:

1.pip install opencv-python

or if you need the full module (cnn, face analysis, shape and etc)

2.pip install opencv-python-contrib

Comment: you are correct when we need to install the package on bare machine, here issue is with anacoda environment.so we shld try what @vardan-agarwal reported above - conda install -c conda-forge opencv